# Java - Merge Map containing list of string as values

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have a `Map` below which I am merging to update the map containing List. Is there a better / concise way of performing this merge operation?

```java
        Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> keys = externalService.getKeys();
        for(String key: keys){
        List<String> value = externalService.get(key);
        myMap.merge(
          key,
          value,
          (existingValue, newValue) -> {
            existingValue.addAll(newValue);
            return existingValue;
          }
        );
        }
```

Comment: What is `keys`?

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, I have now updated it.

Comment: The order of arguments in the remapping function should be reversed - it is oldValue followed by newValue

Comment: @shmosel Can you explain more? I don't see how it could throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite this using Java *stream* (the keys) -> *map* (to values) -> *forEach* (Map#merge). Other than that, I don't see it can be changed much

Comment: Never mind, I thought you were iterating over the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `computeIfAbsent()` if you're willing to allocate the extra list for new keys:

```
for (String key : keys) {
    myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(externalService.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shmosel! The existing implementation has this approach. Is using Map.merge in anyway better than this approach?

Comment: Like I said, this allocates a new list for new keys. It's a slight inefficiency for more concise code (plus defensive copying if you're into that). Up to you if you want to make that tradeoff.